# Calculate submatrix I obtain parse error in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm using lua 5.3.4 version and i want to use continue with goto but i obtain this error message:

unexpected identifier 'goto' near 'end'

This is my code:

```
function getSubmatrix(A, rows, cols, col)
    local submatrix = {}
    local k = 0

    for j = 0, cols do
        if j == col then
            goto continue
        end
        for i = 1, rows do
            submatrix[i-1][k] = A[i][j]
        end
        k = k + 1
    end
    ::continue::
    return submatrix
end
```

I'm using windows 10 and I've downloaded lua from official web page binary version. Lua was working fine except with goto.

Comment: What line# the error message refers to?

Comment: the number line is (7:13)

Comment: The code works fine in the online demo at https://www.lua.org/demo.html. Most likely, you're not running Lua 5.3.

Comment: I'm running lua 5.3 sure. I've downloaded it from the binaries version

Comment: @Tobal - Vanilla Lua doesn't tell column of an error, only line no.  What have you downloaded instead of Lua? :-)

Comment: I've downloaded official Lua and I'm using vscode to write code and execute code. My code was fine until i implemented goto.

Comment: Remove the label and replace `goto continue` by `break`.